# Page gets a trailing forward slash after ".php"

Tags: php

I'm making my first website and have started trying to use php recently.

I'm building the site locally using wamp server.

All my pages use some common html, which is pulled-in using the `include()` statement; each "part" is held in a "parts" folder:

```php
<html>

    <?php include('parts/head.php'); ?>

<body id="blog">

    <?php include('parts/navigation.php'); ?>

    <!-- Page Content Here -->

    <?php include('parts/footer.php'); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

The only difference for each page will be the id of the body tag and the content between the navigation and the footer.

Each page is working just fine except my blog.php page... for some reason when navigated to a trailing slash is added to address, so it reads `http://localhost/mySite/blog.php/` in the address bar.

This trailing slash stops the CSS from doing its thing; it also means you can't navigate back to other pages as the address of those pages just gets tacked on the end, e.g. the home page becomes `http://localhost/mySite/blog.php/home.php`, which is wrong!

I've checked the blog's `<a>` tag in the navigation bar is correct - i.e. it doesn't include this trailing slash, so not sure why this is happening.

I don't know if this is relevant but I was trying to use the blog page to pull in some WordPress blog posts. However, as you can probably see from the above code, I've removed all the WordPress php that would pull through anything from WordPress.

Comment: do you have any rewrite urls?

Comment: i haven't written any (i don't know how yet).

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file in your web folder? Or do you have a folder named blog.php?

Comment: I've got no .htaccess file or folder named "blog.php"